# Any way to install Visual Studio 2008 hotfixes automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1, hotfix

There are several hot fixes for VS 2008 sp1, but it's a mess to install them all manually one by one. Is there some kind of Visual Studio Updater, which installs all the necessary hot fixes automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hotfixes are not tested as thoroughly as Service Packs are and each one comes with a big warning saying you install it on your own risk and you should do so only if you have the problem it fixes. The hotfix might fix that problem, but it might just as well introduce another one. More so, hotfixes are likely only tested in isolation, and having several of them installed might cause problems because that configuration was never fixed.

The last thing you want is to have something installed automatically that might introduce new problems.

Comment: I didn't know til now, that M$ didn't test the studio with all hot fixes installed. 
A hot fix might introduce another issue, but i know i need to install at least 5 hotfixes and it's quite annoying to install them all one by one and click next, next, next in each installer. I just wanted to know if there's an option to install them in some kind of batch manner.

Comment: @Andreas: Why do you think they're called _hot_ fixes? `:)`